# Unable to catch JsonReaderException

Tags: c#, json, exception

I received the following error on the deployed system:

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at JsonWrapper.DeserializeJson[T](String data, ITraceWriter tracer)
```

This is the simplified JsonWrapper.DerserializeJson code from the DLL:

```
public static T DeserializeJson<T>(string data, ITraceWriter tracer) {
    try {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data, new JsonSerializerSettings { TraceWriter = tracer });
    } catch (JsonReaderException jrex) {
        throw new CustomException("Unable to deserialize Json message.", jrex);
    }
}
```

I know why the exception is being thrown, however I am unable to figure out why it is not being caught by the try-catch block.

This code is a DLL that is being consumed by one of our clients. I am hoping this is a fix can be done solely in the DLL.

Any insight into this would be great!

Comment: 1) Is there any chance you have a `JsonReaderException` defined in some other namespace?  2) Is there a possibility that multiple versions of Json.NET have been loaded by the customer?  See [Avoid Loading Multiple Versions of an Assembly into the Same Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx#avoid_loading_multiple_versions) and [Loading Multiple Versions of same Assembly](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2007/04/loading_multiple_versions_of_s.html).

Comment: In the try catch block from your example if you replace `JsonReaderException` with just a general `Exception` are you able to catch anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JsonException might be sourced in another assembly.

If your version of Newtonsoft is different from the version in the other assembly, the specific catch block won't catch it (a generic Exception catch *will*).

The solution is to use the same version of Newtonsoft.

This was mentioned by dbc in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I did find out that I was not catching the correct CustomException in my implementing methods; once fixed, I have not been able to get the JIT error again.

Still haven't figured out why JsonReaderException was shown as a JIT error and not my CustomException.